# xpath get position of an ancestor node

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have an XML structure like the following:

```
<inventory>
    <location>
        <category>
            <children>
                <book>
                    <title>Harry Potter</title>
                    <price>$28.50</price>
                </book>
                <cd>
                    <title>Frozen</title>
                    <price>12.8</price>
                </cd>
            </children>
        </category>
        <category>
            <adult>
                <book>
                    <title>Da vinci code</title>
                    <price>32.50</price>
                </book>
                <cd>
                    <title>Da vinci code</title>
                    <price>13.80</price>
                </cd>
            </adult>
        </category>
    </location>
    <location>
        <category>
            <cooking>
                <book>
                    <title>everyday Italian</title>
                    <price>30.50</price>
                </book>
            </cooking>
        </category>
    </location>
</inventory>
```

What I want to print is:

```
Location category# category  title       price
1        1         children  Harry       28.50
2        1         cooking   everyday... 30.50
1        2         cd        Da vinci code 13.8
```

If I'm currently on each of the `<title>` elements, how do I get the position of `<location>` and `<category>`?

What I've tried:

```
count(ancestor::location/preceding-silbing::location) + 1
count(ancestor::category/preceding-silbing::category) + 1
```

But none of them work.

Comment: Thank you Joel for helping me re-structure my xml code. It really takes me long time to do the tag...

Comment: are you using pure xpath? or are you using xslt?

Comment: Try `count(ancestor::location[1]/preceding-sibling::location) + 1` and `count(ancestor::category[1]/preceding-sibling::category) + 1`

Comment: I use xslt 2.0. I tried to add [1] after the ancestor location but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using XSLT 2.0 try using the more powerful [`xsl:number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#number) instead of `count()`.

Location:

```
<xsl:number select="ancestor::location"/>
```

Category:

```
<xsl:number select="ancestor::category"/>
```

---

Here's a more detailed example. (Note, this is just for illustration purposes; it's probably not the most efficient example.)

**XML Input**

```
<inventory>
    <location>
        <category>
            <children>
                <book>
                    <title>Harry Potter</title>
                    <price>$28.50</price>
                </book>
                <cd>
                    <title>Frozen</title>
                    <price>12.8</price>
                </cd>
            </children>
        </category>
        <category>
            <adult>
                <book>
                    <title>Da vinci code</title>
                    <price>32.50</price>
                </book>
                <cd>
                    <title>Da vinci code</title>
                    <price>13.80</price>
                </cd>
            </adult>
        </category>
    </location>
    <location>
        <category>
            <cooking>
                <book>
                    <title>everyday Italian</title>
                    <price>30.50</price>
                </book>
            </cooking>
        </category>
    </location>
</inventory>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:local="local">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="column-widths">
        <cols>
            <col name="location" width="10"/>
            <col name="categorynbr" width="11"/>
            <col name="category" width="{max((string-length('category'),//category/*/string-length(name())))+2}"/>
            <col name="title" width="{max((string-length('title'),//category/*/book/title/string-length(normalize-space())))+2}"/>
            <col name="price" width="{max((string-length('price'),//category/*/book/price/string-length(normalize-space())))+2}"/>
        </cols>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:function name="local:padValue">
        <xsl:param name="colname"/>
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:variable name="padding">
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer($column-widths/*/col[@name=$colname]/@width) - string-length($value)">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>                    
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($value,$padding)"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(local:padValue('location','Location'),
            local:padValue('categorynbr','category#'),
            local:padValue('category','category'),
            local:padValue('title','title'),
            local:padValue('price','price'),'&#xA;')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/*/book">
            <xsl:sort>
                <xsl:number select="ancestor::category"/>
            </xsl:sort>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="book">
        <xsl:variable name="loc">
            <xsl:number select="ancestor::location"/>            
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="cat">
            <xsl:number select="ancestor::category"/>            
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(local:padValue('location',$loc),
            local:padValue('categorynbr',$cat),
            local:padValue('category',../local-name()),
            local:padValue('title',normalize-space(title)),
            local:padValue('price',normalize-space(price)),'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
Location  category#  category  title             price   
1         1          children  Harry Potter      $28.50  
2         1          cooking   everyday Italian  30.50   
1         2          adult     Da vinci code     32.50
```

Comment: this works well! Thank you very much Daniel. There's lots of thing to learn from your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that this is what you're after:

Your context node is either of the `title` elements in the input document. Now you want to know

- The (one-based) index of the `location` element that your context node is contained in, within its parent `inventory` element
- The (one-based) index of the `category` element that your context node is contained in, within its parent `category` element

For the provided XML input, this can be achieved with the XPath expressions

```
count(ancestor::location/preceding-sibling::location) + 1
```

and

```
count(ancestor::category/preceding-sibling::category) + 1
```

Make sure that axis and node-test are separated by two colons (corrected by edit). Also make sure `preceding-sibling` is spelled correctly.

You *can* add the predicate `[1]` after the location steps `ancestor::location` and `ancestor::category` to explicitly state that you're after the first ancestor in reverse document order (i.e., the closest ancestor). This would be *necessary* if the XML contained nested `location` or `category` elements.

Comment: your assumption is correct. Well I made up this case just want to learn how to use xPath. But this is just one of a similar logical which is called by a fo block from my work. Above xpath works for my make up scenario very well but somehow not for my work. I have to figure out why this doesn't work for my work.